# how to resize image in CSS?

Tags: css

I've got the page divided into different parts like header, footer and body. Now i need to set images on the background of header and footer. Should i choose a bigger image which can be re sized according to user's system dimension or should i keep it constant size?

How to keep an image withing the section that has been decided for it?

Comment: If you want to use CSS3 'background-size' you can prepare few images with different sizes and choose one depending on user's screen resolution. You will save traffic and make page loading faster in this way. And background image will be within the container by default.

Answer (score 1):

i'd create separate images for the smaller devices as the smaller file sizes will help when loading on tablet or mobile. Load in the different images using media queries

```
 header-bg-desktop.jpg
 header-bg-tablet.jpg
 header-bg-mobile.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree using separate images is beneficial for performance (especially on phones), though if you wanted to do this with CSS only, you can use **`background-size: cover`**, which will ensure the background image does not stretch, but also fills in the entire parent container.

E.G. http://jsfiddle.net/YNBw9/

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `background-size: cover` to get the images to fill the containers at different size. You also want to use media queries, if possible, to deliver the right sized image to the right screens. That is, you don't want to overload a small screen with more pixels than it needs (not the screen, the bandwidth and load time) and you don't want to scale up a crappy image for larger screens.

http://plnkr.co/edit/bMryzPTGzUK6Y5BbDpWh?p=preview shows an example. Resize the right pane.

More on media queries:
https://www.google.com/search?q=media+queries

More on background-size:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

It largely depends upon your website's target audience.

If you are going to target mobile, tablet and desktop all three user bases, then you must supply images for all of them with different background image code via CSS.

Here is a very good reference to get you started,

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

If you target desktop users only then you need to supply one-background image size and that should be enough.

Example code,

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image:url('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/logo.jpg');
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
```